# Crystal reports Login failed even with authorized credential Ms access C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, crystal-reports

Why...?

I have a Ms access database file that set a username and password for it.
e.x. Admin 1234

but when I set this user and pass to crystal reports it says that this is wrong credential.

before setting user&pass crystal reports asked for credentials when I execute it on another machine.

```
var cr=new CrystalReport();
.
.
.
cr.SetDatabaseLogon(user,pass);// the report has two subreports
cr.subreports[0].SetDatabaseLogon(user,pass);
cr.subreports[1].SetDatabaseLogon(user,pass);
```

Am I wrong or crystalreports is ?

Comment: I can guarantee you Crystal reports is not wrong.

Comment: Whats with the Why..??

Comment: Check out this answer:
[link to example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35862733/crystal-report-invalid-index-exception-from-hresult-0x8002000b-disp-e-badin)